# How to select column and retrieve from it all the rows values using VB.NET and ASP.NET MVC using data model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have connected the database using Entity Framework (data model) using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2019. I want to retrieve all the data from the database table.

Then I added a controller with views for ASP.NET MVC 5. It automatically creates a view with the data from the database.

The question is: I cannot get or loop on the data if I want to change the data from code or add new values from code I cannot get for example row 0 column 0. anyone can help me with how to add this data to the list or loop on it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following code to get data or loop on the data.

My model class is Student:

```
 Function Index() As ActionResult

            Dim myType As Type = GetType(Student)
            Dim pro As PropertyInfo() = myType.GetProperties()
            Dim l As List(Of Student) = db.Students.ToList()
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To pro.Length - 1
                Response.Write(pro(i).Name + "<br />")
                Dim list1 = l.Select(Function(f) f.GetType().GetProperty(pro(i).Name).GetValue(f)).ToList()
                Response.Write(String.Join(",", list1.ToArray()) + "<br />")
            Next i

            Return View(db.Students.ToList())

        End Function
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you it’s helpful, now I want to get property of each design I have for example I have name and unit and value as a column name I want to loop on them first I want to finish all the rows in the unit column then I want to go to next column and get all the rows values etc. I hope I can explain my logic thanks you in advance

Comment: @Reem Elshenawy, I have updated the code.  If you already have known the column name and the column count is not large, I suggest that you can get all the rows value by using linq based on the column name. You can check if the above code works for you.

Comment: I will try it but if I have too much data so I don't think it's an effective way but I will try it thank you

Comment: @Reem Elshenawy, sorry for that, I didn't consider that. Now I have updated code to use reflection to get property and loop the property to get each list of each column.